# cakephp passing array to Xml::build()

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, multidimensional-array

CakePHP doc says I can transform an array to XML using XML::build(). All I get are errors. Here's my post to the #cakephp irc.

i have a [multi-dimension data set](http://bin.cakephp.org/saved/74054), for which I made a [wrapper function to output my xml](http://bin.cakephp.org/view/1721853738). It errors out with [this message](http://bin.cakephp.org/view/1440993672). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As suggested, I changed the call to $xml = Xml::build(array('root' => $_records));. Now I get the error: Warning (2): SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 3: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document [CORE\Cake\Utility\Xml.php, line 177] String could not be parsed as XML

Comment: Adding a return element removed the warning $xml = Xml::build(array('return' => 'simplexml', 'root' => $_records));. Error has been replaced with Invalid input.

Comment: After stepping through the app, I found where the app bombs. http://bin.cakephp.org/view/403624274. The problem is I don't know why or how to fix it.

Comment: Ok, here's another attempt. http://bin.cakephp.org/view/724808941. The output looks wrong, which would explain the errors. But it doesn't explain why the array is encoded incorrectly.

Comment: I've since learned that the array's root element is numeric and the parent and child elements are actually constructed as child siblings of that root. Definitely not what I want. I'm creating the array like this: $invoices = $this->Invoice->find('all');. Nothing special, but it's giving me fits trying to understand why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Learned that XML::build() doesn't handle multi-dimensional arrays very well. Finally found a custom function that did the trick. http://snipplr.com/view/3491/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a class I found that traverses multi-dimensional php arrays and converts to xml.

[Convert PHP Array to XML or Simple XML Object if you wish](http://snipplr.com/view/3491/)